# A symbolic logic problem generator, or at least a huge ready-made collection?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am an amateur student of formal logic, and I was wondering other Gensler's LogiCola program, is there anything out there that produces logic proof problems? For example, the LogiCola program I am using right now will spit out

1. ~(B -> S)
2. ~K -> ~C
3. ~K -> C    // ~((~S -> ~K) v ~B)

So, it will spit out premises and a conclusion you are supposed to provide a proof for--it does this for predicate logic as well. Very good, very fun stuff. Anyway, I just wanted to cover my bases to make sure I was not missing out on any other similar random problem generator--or maybe a huge readymade collection of such problems (like the For Dummies "1,001 Algebra Problems" series for math). Thanks guys!